# How to copy data values separated with `:` from multiple text file to csv with respected headers with python?

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Trying to copy text next to variables like type, number, name from text file to csv with following form:

```
Type      Name     Phone     email     Mailing Address
```

I Have lots of text file in this form:

```
Type: zxyz
Number: 34567892
Name: xyzzzxx, yuw
Phone Number: 000-000-0000
Email Address: any@gmail.com
Mailing Address: bla bla bla
```

I am unable to copy text next to search string from text file and write it into csv file.

Comment: What have you already got, and what about that code is not working? You need to provide a [MCVE] for people to be able to help you solve your problem.

Comment: more info is needed like what are you trying to search? what info you want to copy.

Comment: @rakesh i am trying to copy values of type, number ,phone number,email address ext from text file to csv with respected headers in rows.

Comment: @errata Master, i am trying to copy data values from multiple text file to csv with respected headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the contents of one file to a dictionary like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    d = dict(line.strip().split(': ') for line in f)
```

Then write the dictionary to a CSV file using [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter):

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['Type', 'Name', 'Phone Number', 'Email Address', 'Mailing Address']
filenames = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']

with open('out.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames)
    writer.writerheader()
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename) as f:
            d = dict(line.strip().split(': ') for line in f)
            writer.writerow(d)
```

This will copy all of the data from the input files to a single CSV file. If you want to exclude some fields adjust the `fieldnames` and remove the unwanted fields from the dictionary prior to calling `writerow()`. You can also rename the fields by changing the field name in both `fieldnames` and the dictionary.